# Methods for smoothing contour lines

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour, smoothing

I have a database P with columns X, Y and Z:

```
x=0:1:50;
r=3.*rand(1,51);
P=[cos(x')+r',sin(x')+r',sin(x'+r').*cos(x')+r'];
P = sortrows(P,[1,2]);
N = 500;
xv = linspace(min(P(:,1)), max(P(:,1)), N);
yv = linspace(min(P(:,2)), max(P(:,2)), N);
[X,Y] = ndgrid(xv, yv);
Z = griddata(P(:,1), P(:,2), P(:,3), X, Y);
contourf(X, Y, Z, 35)
```

With the code above, I get the following subplot (right):

[image]

***This "angularity" arises due to the addition of a vector r of random values ​​to the data. How to smooth out this angularity and make the graph smoother?***

I tried to increase `N` to 2500. It did not give a significant result (in fact, it stopped changing significantly after `N`=1500).

Comment: Please try and create a [mcve] which doesn't require us to download files from external sites. Without doing so, I'd guess you're trying to subsample at a higher resolution than your original data, which either contains flat regions or there's some linear interpolation going on. What does the surface look like at its raw sampling?

Answer (score 1):

To smooth your 2D data you can use a 2D convolution, with the operator [`conv2`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)

With your example data:

```
n = 10 ;
kernel = ones(n)/n.^2 ;
Zs = conv2(Z, kernel,'same') ;

contourf(X, Y, Zs, 35) ;
title(sprintf('Filter size: n=%d',n))
```

will yield:

[image: smoothed n=10]

---

You have to adjust the filter size (the parameter `n`) until you get the desired result. For example with `n=20` you will get:

[image: smoothed n=20]

And for `n=50`:

[image: smoothed n=50]

---

A few things to keep in mind:

- Since you have `NaN` in your matrix `Z`, the filtering will erode the border of you initial domain. The stronger the filtering/smoothing (higher `n`), the more erosion you will notice until very little non-`NaN` data is left .
- For it to be a *smoothing* operation and not another transform or filtering, the convolution `kernel` has to be built so (i) all the elements are of equal value, and (ii) the total sum of the elements should be 1.

A quick demonstration with `n=2`:

```
>> n=2
n =
     2
>> kernel = ones(n)/n.^2
kernel =
                      0.25                      0.25
                      0.25                      0.25
>> sum(sum(kernel))
ans =
     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Everything is exactly as you described. There were also several ideas for spline interpolation of contour lines and data smoothing. But I haven't implemented them yet.